# Regex to get a filename from a url

Tags: regex

I am trying to write a regex to get the filename from a url if it exists.

This is what I have so far:

```
(?:[^/][\d\w\.]+)+$
```

So from the url `http://www.foo.com/bar/baz/filename.jpg`, I should match `filename.jpg`

Unfortunately, I match anything after the last `/`.

How can I tighten it up so it only grabs it if it looks like a filename?

Comment: `(?:/)[\d\w]+\.[\d\w]+$`?

Comment: You probably don't want to use a regular expression for this if you don't have to.  For example, if you're using PHP, then use PHP's [`parse_url()` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php).

Comment: Are you trying to extract the filename from the URL? I wanted to know your real requirement..like if you just want to get the filename from URL you could just use javascript, or it that you need the regex itself.

Comment: Next time you ask you should give more details like if the url can have properties after the filename for example.

Comment: define what look like a filename? any specific extension?

Comment: I am using C# Mvc, it is to map a url route, so that any url that contains an image file name at the end of the url is mapped to a specific controller. Filenames are not controlled, so could be any valid filename for a url, and of course will have an image extension.

Comment: u use c# but u test using regexpal that is based on javascript..javascript dosent support lookbehind but c# do

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Non Pcre

```
(?:[^/][\d\w\.]+)$(?<=\.\w{3,4})
```

Pcre

```
(?:[^/][\d\w\.]+)$(?<=(?:.jpg)|(?:.pdf)|(?:.gif)|(?:.jpeg)|(more_extension))
```

[Demo](http://regexr.com?33gfh)

Since you test using `regexpal.com` that is based on javascript(doesnt support lookbehind), try this instead

```
(?=\w+\.\w{3,4}$).+
```

Comment: this doesnt seem to work at all, i am testing using regexpal.com

Comment: @shenku it work fine, im testing it using regexbuddy, what kind of url u testing?..mind to give it to me so i can test?

Comment: @shenku try the javascript flavour at regexpal

Comment: ps. i think this will get me there, i am going to give it a try today and will mark as correct (if it works ;D)

Comment: @shenku no worries, just add a comment if this regex not functioning as u expected

Comment: hi, i noticed that it excludes some characters, can this be made a bit more robust? for example the valid filename `imagename%20(Custom).jpg` wont work...

Comment: @shenku are u using pcre or non pcre

Comment: It appears your linked demo no longer works. The section `(?<=` gives the error, `Error: Lookbehind is not supported in JavaScript.` I suggest editing your link to include a demo that shows your expression(s) working

Comment: I slightly changed the @slier expression to this one: *re.findall('(?:[^/]+)$(?<=(?:.jpg)|(?:.pdf))', list)*, in a python implementation. It allowed me to get the whole filename after the URL "/".

Answer (score 43):

The examples above fails to get file name "file-1.name.zip" from this URL:

```
"http://sub.domain.com/sub/sub/handler?file=data/file-1.name.zip&v=1"
```

So I created my REGEX version:

```
[^/\\&\?]+\.\w{3,4}(?=([\?&].*$|$))
```

Explanation:

```
[^/\\&\?]+          # file name - group of chars without URL delimiters
\.\w{3,4}           # file extension - 3 or 4 word chars
(?=([\?&].*$|$))    # positive lookahead to ensure that file name is at the end of string or there is some QueryString parameters, that needs to be ignored
```

Comment: this should have been the accepted answer if you are using anything like Java or C#

Comment: Can you please expand on files with two extensions i.e tar.gz, tar.bz2?

Comment: Aside from the fact that I think this is the best answer posted here it is still not perfect as It fails to exclude the fragment part of the url https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_fragment so I think `[^/\\&\?#]+\.\w{3,4}(?=([\?&#].*$|$))` is even better.

Comment: unescaped char /, should be this one `[^\/\\&\?]+\.\w{3,4}(?=([\?&].*$|$))`

Answer (score 19):

This one works well for me.

```
(\w+)(\.\w+)+(?!.*(\w+)(\.\w+)+)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, doesn't work if the filename has a dash.

Comment: @Vlad does `/([\w-]+)(\.\w+)+(?!.*(\w+)(\.\w+)+)/` help with the hyphen? The part I changed is the first grouping: `(\w+)` -> `([\w-]+)`

Answer (score 15):

```
(?:.+\/)(.+)
```

Select all up to the last forward slash (/), capture everything after this forward slash. Use subpattern $1.

Comment: `(?:.+\/)([^#?]+)` to filter out params in the end of filename

Comment: This is by far the simplest and should be the accepted answer

Comment: Its simplicity allowed me to easily modify it grab just the "slug" in front of an optional file extension as follows: `location.href.match(/(?:.+\/)(.+?)(\..+)?$/)[1]`

Comment: This isn't sufficient, as it leaves the query string.

Answer (score 8):

I'm using this:

```
(?<=\/)[^\/\?#]+(?=[^\/]*$)
```

Explanation:

(?<=): positive look behind, asserting that a string has this expression, but not matching it.

(?<=/): positive look behind for the literal forward slash "/", meaning I'm looking for an expression which is preceded, but does not match a forward slash.

[^/\?#]+: one or more characters which are not either "/", "?" or "#", stripping search params and hash.

(?=[^/]*$): positive look ahead for anything not matching a slash, then matching the line ending. This is to ensure that the last forward slash segment is selected.

Example usage:

```js
const urlFileNameRegEx = /(?<=\/)[^\/\?#]+(?=[^\/]*$)/;

const testCases = [
  "https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserverInit#yo",
  "https://developer.mozilla.org/static/fonts/locales/ZillaSlab-Regular.subset.bbc33fb47cf6.woff2",
  "https://developer.mozilla.org/static/build/styles/locale-en-US.520ecdcaef8c.css?is-nice=true"
];

testCases.forEach(testStr => console.log(`The file of ${testStr} is ${urlFileNameRegEx.exec(testStr)[0]}`))
```

Comment: Nice work! In regex online tests works fine, but in PHP 7.4 (not tried other), the following url returns "tr". It should return nothing. (https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=841681186336846&ev=PageView&noscript=1/). Can someone tell what is happening?

Comment: @LucianDex I tested this with your URL for PHP >= 7.3 at https://regex101.com/, and correctly, there is no match. It could be the case that the particular RegEx engine you are using doesn't support positive or negative lookbehinds. They are not always supported in older RegEx engines.

Comment: This is the way.

Answer (score 2):

It might work as well:

```
(\w+\.)+\w+$
```

Answer (score 1):

You know what your delimiters look like, so you don't need a regex. Just `split` the string. Since you didn't mention a language, here's an implementation in Perl:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $url = "http://www.foo.com/bar/baz/filename.jpg";
my @url_parts = split/\//,$url;

my $filename = $url_parts[-1];

if(index($filename,".") > 0 )
{
    print "It appears as though we have a filename of $filename.\n";
}
else
{
    print "It seems as though the end of the URL ($filename) is not a filename.\n";
}
```

Of course, if you need to worry about specific filename extensions (png,jpg,html,etc), then adjust appropriately.

Comment: Just a guess, but maybe downvoter wanted more of an explanation on what your code does? Also, it's a bit ambiguous, but OP made it sound like you need to account for the possibility of having more text after the URL that isn't separated by `/`: _"Unfortunately, I match anything after the last `/`"_ Just guessing here :P

Answer (score 0):

```
> echo "http://www.foo.com/bar/baz/filename.jpg" | sed 's/.*\/\([^\/]*\..*\)$/\1/g'
filename.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you will be using javascript:

```
        var fn=window.location.href.match(/([^/])+/g);
        fn = fn[fn.length-1]; // get the last element of the array
        alert(fn.substring(0,fn.indexOf('.')));//alerts the filename
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code you may use:

```
\/([\w.][\w.-]*)(?<!\/\.)(?<!\/\.\.)(?:\?.*)?$
```

names "." and ".." are not considered as normal.

you can play with this regexp here https://regex101.com/r/QaAK06/1/:

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using the [JavaScript URL object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL), you can use the pathname combined with the following RegExp:

`.*\/(.[^(\/)]+)`

#### Benefit:

It matches anything at the end of the path, but excludes a possible trailing slash (as long as there aren't *two* trailing slashes)!

Answer (score -1):

Try this one instead:

```
(?:[^/]*+)$(?<=\..*)
```

Answer (score -1):

This is worked for me, no matter if you have '.' or without '.' it take the sufix of url

```
\/(\w+)[\.|\w]+$
```