# How to split a string in db2?

Tags: regex, string, split, db2

I've some URL's in my `cas_fnd_dwd_det` table,

```
casi_imp_urls                           cas_code
-----------------------------------    -----------
www.casiac.net/fnds/CASI/qnxp.pdf      
www.casiac.net/fnds/casi/as.pdf        
www.casiac.net/fnds/casi/vindq.pdf     
www.casiac.net/fnds/CASI/mnip.pdf
```

how do i copy the letters between last '/' and '.pdf' to another column

expected outcome

```
casi_imp_urls                           cas_code
-----------------------------------    -----------
www.casiac.net/fnds/CASI/qnxp.pdf      qnxp
www.casiac.net/fnds/casi/as.pdf        as   
www.casiac.net/fnds/casi/vindq.pdf     vindq
www.casiac.net/fnds/CASI/mnip.pdf      mnip
```

the below URL's are static

```
www.casiac.net/fnds/CASI/
www.casiac.net/fnds/casi/
```

Advise, how do i select the codes between last '/' and '.pdf' ?

Comment: `SELECT REPLACE((REPLACE('www.casiac.net/fnds/CASI/qnxp.pdf','www.casiac.net/fnds/CASI/','')),'.pdf','' )
FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1;`  but how do I handle capital and non capital letters in the URL ? Advise please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to take a look at [REGEXP_SUBSTR](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0061497.html). It allows to apply a regular expression. Db2 has string processing functions, but the regex function may be the easiest solution. See [SO question on regex and URI parts](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bregex%5D%20uri) for different ways of writing the expression. The following would return the last slash, filename and the extension:

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('http://fobar.com/one/two/abc.pdf','\/(\w)*.pdf' ,1,1) 
   FROM sysibm.sysdummy1
```

> /abc.pdf

The following uses REPLACE and the [pattern is from this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14473180/regex-to-get-a-filename-from-a-url) with the pdf file extension added. It splits the string in three groups: everything up to the last slash, then the file name, then the ".pdf". The `'$1'` returns the group 1 (groups start with 0). Group 2 would be the ".pdf".

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('http://fobar.com/one/two/abc.pdf','(?:.+\/)(.+)(.pdf)','$1' ,1,1) 
   FROM sysibm.sysdummy1
```

> abc

You could apply LENGTH and SUBSTR to extract the relevant part or try to build that into the regex.

Comment: i'm getting an error this function (REGEXP_SUBSTR) is does not exists. My DB2 version is DB2 v9.5.0.10.
Any alternative method to suggest ?

Comment: That version is looooong out of service. You could use RIGHT (https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000844.html) to consume the last 4 characters (".pdf") and from there go to the slash.

Comment: @data_henrik Could you explain ```\/(\w)*.pdf```` pattern expression?

Comment: Find a slash followed by any repeated word character followed by ".pdf".

Answer (score 0):

For older Db2 versions than 11.1. Not sure if it works for 9.5, but definitely should work since 9.7.
Try this as is.

```
with cas_fnd_dwd_det (casi_imp_urls) as (values  
  'www.casiac.net/fnds/CASI/qnxp.pdf'
, 'www.casiac.net/fnds/casi/as.pdf'
, 'www.casiac.net/fnds/casi/vindq.pdf'
, 'www.casiac.net/fnds/CASI/mnip.PDF'
)
select 
  casi_imp_urls
, xmlcast(xmlquery('fn:replace($s, ".*/(.*)\.pdf", "$1", "i")' passing casi_imp_urls as "s") as varchar(50)) cas_code
from cas_fnd_dwd_det
```

Comment: Thanks Mark. This is perfectly working for me. 
Now, If my URL contains PDF in uppercase (www.casiac.net/fnds/CASI/mnip.PDF) , how can I get the expected result ?

Comment: Added a parameter for case-insensitive search.

Comment: The above should work since V9.1 when XQuery was introduced.